# Changing basin spout help

Tags: faucet, spout

I want to change the tap set of my basin.

I'm having trouble loosening the underside locking nut under the spout. The space is very tight

I tried a basin spanner but can't get a proper grip

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: First spray it with a penetrating compound of some type and while that soaks maybe a day or so get another wrench, the one in the picture is quite large. Good luck, that is a problem that may not work out other then replacement.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I ended up removing the sink.